# Crashing I suspect with onLocationChanged don't know what the bug is

Tags: android, gps

Help!  This is my first app outside of a simple Udacity course, please be kind.

I want the gps accurately once.  The user of my app won't need gps refreshes.  Nevertheless I believe I need a onLocationChanged listener to get an accurate gps read.

It crashes.  In MainActivity it can hit the second Toast after calling MyLocationListener class.  Which would suggest the bug is in MainActivity's getGPS.  But I don't see where.  I presume the listener allows the MainActivity to continue while it searches for GPS?

The gps on my phone is working I have downloaded a tester app.  I get looks though, leaving the house in my Y-fronts.

Here's a stack trace from crashalytics.

http://crashes.to/s/54d65de993b

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
   at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:101)
   at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:258)
   at com.example.android.carfinder.MyLocationListener.onLocationChanged(MyLocationListener.java:28)
   at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:281)
   at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:210)
   at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:226)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

So questions,

```
    1. what's causing the crash?
    2. When I've got a gps, how do I turn the listener off, till the button is re-pressed? 
    3. Why doesn't progressDialog show while it searches for gps?
```

MainActivity, getGPS activates with an onClick event:

```
 public void getGPS(View view) {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if(displayGpsStatus() == false) {
        Log.i("getGPS", "GPS turned off");
        return;
    }
    // GPS is working
    //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Getting GPS lock", "Not much longer love");

    Log.i("getGPS", "trying for new co-ords");
    LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
    try {
        Toast.makeText(this, "activating locationListener", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener); //5000, 10
        Log.i("getGPS", "just returned from MyLocationListener Class");
    }
    catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.i("getGPS", "no permission to use GPS");
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Did you block GPS permission on install?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        return;
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "continuing, is address and time updated?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // Got GPS so hide the progress bar
    //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    progressDialog.dismiss();

    // update the date and address views
    //saveDateTime();
    //updateAddressView();
    return;
}
```

MyLocationListener:

```
public class MyLocationListener extends MainActivity implements LocationListener {
     String TAG = "MyLocationListener Class";

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    Log.i("onLocationChanged", "in outside class");

    Toast.makeText(
            getBaseContext(),
            "Location changed: Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() + " Lng: "
                    + loc.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String longitude = "Longitude: " + loc.getLongitude();
    Log.i(TAG, longitude);
    String latitude = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude();
    Log.i(TAG, latitude);
    // TODO need to check latitude and longitude accessible from MainActivity

    /*------- To get city name from coordinates -------- */
    // from here we're reverse geo-coding to get the address
    String address = null;
    String city = null;
    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses;
    try {
        addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            //System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
            address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("MyLocationListener", "No address found");
    }
    String savedAddress = address + ",  " + city;
    if(address == null && city == null) {
        savedAddress = "couldn't fathom address, tap view on map to check";
    }
    TextView addressTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.approxAddress);
    addressTextView.setText(savedAddress);
    // save it to permanent memory
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
    mEditor.putString("savedAddress", savedAddress).apply();
    mEditor.putString("savedLongitude", longitude).apply();
    mEditor.putString("savedLatitude", latitude).apply();

    Log.i("MyLocationListener", "SAVED address, gps: ");
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "MyLocListener: GPS disabled DOH!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "MyLocListener: GPS enabled :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "MyLocListener: GPS status changed?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Comment: What's the crash log?

Comment: where is the initialization of your progressBar ?

Comment: How do I get the crash log?  My PC can't leave the house, so can't run my phone attached to my debugger.  I intialized the progressBar in onCreate.  I changed it to ProgressDialog though, because that avoids messing with the xml, just floats on top.  But it doesn't show, grrr.

Comment: Posted the crash log.  Love your help.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from a call to `Toast.makeText`. My guess is that you're trying to use a Toast (and with it `getBaseContext`) before the Activity is created. The context doesn't exist yet at that point.

Try replacing your `Toast.makeText` calls by `Log.i` calls. If that gets rid of the error, and you do need the Toast, just check the context for not being null before you call `Toast.makeText`.

Comment: Maybe could be a good idea create a constructor on MyLocationListener where you can pass by parameter the context of the application base to be sure that is using the correct context.

Comment: Hey guys, these are great suggestions.  Yes it's definitely getBaseContext().  I removed all the toasts, but it still left one call to getBaseContext when I create a Geocoder object "Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this.getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());".  I've tried passing in the context to a constructor, but when I try and create a MyLocationListener object it doesn't like "new MyLocationListener(this);" or any variation like "getApplicationContext()".  Grrrr.  I think I need to learn more.  Thanks for your help :)